# React Drum Machine

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't get my react drum machine to detect window keypress and play sound.
Please help with a bit of explanation. Thanks.

[Fork App on CodePen App](https://codepen.io/_kouqhar/pen/PoPdwGE?editors=0110)

```
 handleKeyPress(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === this.props.keyCode) {
      this.playSound();
    }
  }

  playSound() {
    const sound = document.getElementById(`${this.props.keyTrigger}`);
    sound.currentTime = 0;
    sound.volume = 3
    sound.play();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'currentTime' of null
    at App.playSound (pen.js:81)
    at App.handleKeyPress (pen.js:76)
```

The error refers to this line:

```
const sound = document.getElementById(`${this.props.keyTrigger}`);
```

You're not passing any props to App component. You should probaby extract the key from the event in the event handler.